# Strange polygons appear in fullscreen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Another interesting Minecraft "feature" here. When I play from inside the browser and hit F11 for fullscreen, I get wildly moving polygons flashing across the entire screen:

[image: Polygons]
[image: More polygons]

It doesn't affect character movement or button triggers, but it makes the game world hard to navigate. There are about 30 of these polygonal messes per second, and it makes me dizzy to try and ignore and play through it. Strangely, the in-game GUIs are fairly easy to see, though are not entirely unscathed by the polygons.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems with in-browser fullscreen? Is there a way to fix it, perhaps by changing my display settings or browser Java settings somehow?

Comment: That's trippy...

Comment: you should see it in real-time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously the first fix is to update your graphics card drivers and Java to their latest versions. What video card are you using?

Comment: video card is nvidia 8800GTS, so it should be a non-issue

Comment: @Keaanu: I'm not sure why you're saying it's a non-issue.  I have an 8800 GTX that was plagued with similar graphical glitches in some games until I upgraded the drivers (granted the new drivers brought about different issues, but it at least fixed that particular problem).

Comment: Drivers are up to date, and Java is at Version 6 Update 23 (latest).

Comment: Turns out it was the graphics card. I'm gonna cash in on that lifetime warranty. Good call, by the way.

Comment: hoc can a graphics card create something like that? youcan still see part of the world... so wierd

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, except it was just a single face of a wall at a time.

My Solution:

Play in normal size for at least 30 minutes (this seems to stabilize the game), then try fullscreen, or play offline.